# How to place order with paypal express checkout in Magento 1.9 Rest api

Tags: api, magento, paypal, payment-gateway

I made payment via paypal.I am new in this framework. Don't have any idea, in which table I have to update. I f you guys give some ideas about implementation flow then it will be very helpful.

Below I have tried yet

```
                  $quoteId=128551;
                  $customerId=29395;
                  $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
                  $website = Mage::app()->getWebsite();

                  $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStoreId($store->getStoreId())->load($quoteId);
                  $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
                  //Assign the customer to quote
                  $quote->assignCustomer($customer);
                  //Set currency for the quote
                  $quote->setCurrency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseCurrencyCode());

                  $billingAddressId=29971;
                  $customAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($billingAddressId);

                  $quoteShippingAddress = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_address');
                  $quoteShippingAddress->setData($customAddress);
                  $quote->setShippingAddress($quoteShippingAddress);
                  // fixed shipping method
                  $quote->getShippingAddress()->setShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping');

                  $quote->getShippingAddress()->setPaymentMethod('paypal_express');

                  $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
                  $quote->getShippingAddress()->collectShippingRates();

                  //Set payment method for the quote

                 $quote->getPayment()->importData(array('method' => 'paypal_express')); 

            try {

              $quote->collectTotals()->save();
              //Create order from quote
              $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
              $service->submitAll();
              $increment_id = $service->getOrder()->getRealOrderId();
              $orderId = $service->getOrder()->getId();
              Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')
                ->setLastQuoteId($quote->getId())
                ->setLastSuccessQuoteId($quote->getId())
                ->clearHelperData();



            echo   $msg = 'Order has been successfully created.';


            } catch (Exception $e) {

               $msg = $e->getMessage();
            }
```